# Difference between bson.objectid.ObjectId and bson.ObjectId?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have generated an ObjectId through two different methods as follows:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> # Method one
>>> from bson.objectid import ObjectId
>>> idA = ObjectId()
>>> print(idA)
4e9c45b91d41c8079a000000

>>> # Method two
>>> import bson
>>> idB = bson.ObjectId()
>>> print(idB)
4e9c45ca1d41c8079a000001
```

Question> What is this difference between two methods? When should I use which?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [5]: bson.ObjectId
Out[5]: bson.objectid.ObjectId
```

They are exactly the same thing.

Comment: Also, each time you construct a new ObjectId you will get a new value.